# DevOps CICD - Parallel stages Deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, cicd, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a new release pipeline contains 75 stages, when I create release each one of the stages take in average 5 minutes to complete deployment process then move to next one, that means it needs almost 7 hours to deploy all stages!

How can I make all stages working together (in parallel) to finish deployment in almost 5 minutes.
If this is not possible, how to speed up the process in general?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So first need to have [parallel agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted) configured at the organization level.  This will still be a bottle neck interms of how many will run simultaneously unless purchasing 75 agents.

The second will be in the Azure YAML Pipeline [by default a stage depends on its predecessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#stage). Just add:

```
dependsOn:
```

Without a value. This will let ADO know the stage can execute w/o any dependencies.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/stages-stage?view=azure-pipelines